# OpenCV : Build with lesser features

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a C++ app that uses OpenCV. Currently i am statically linking the OpenCV libs into my app. This is adding an extra overhead of 6+ MB.

Ideally i would like to remove some of the features that i am not using in OpenCV. The features am using are,

1. Capture frames from Webcam.
2. Face detection.
3. Image formats (JPEG, PNG).
4. Image rotation & resizing.

Is it possible to remove other features and trim down the libs?

My C++ app is developed in Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to link STATICALLY, using LIBRARIES

Answer (score 0):

If you have the OpenCV source code set up in your PC, create your own dll from the opencv source code with exporting only the required features